# Sorting with Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, express, mongoose

I am trying to sort my MongoDB data. I have a rentals Schema shown below which includes a "featured" item. IF the featured item is set to true (users can do this on their end) I want the featured item to be shown above the rest of the Rentals. In other words I need to sort the mongo data that has featured = true to the top.

How would I change my code below to do this?

**Here is my rental Schema:**

```
var rentalsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    featured: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    Title: String,
});
```

**Here is what I've tried so far (and is not working.)**

```
router.get('/rentals', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('rentals').find().sort({
        featured: 1
    }).toArray(function(err, items) {

    });
});
```

Comment: 1 stands for asc
-1 stands for descending, so if you want to have featured with value 1 at beggining you should replace sort object with {featured: -1}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `.sort({ featured: 1 })` to `.sort({ featured: -1 })`. You want those with `featured` value of `true` to come before those with false `false`.

It looks like default sorting by boolean fields goes from false to true (maybe because of 0 and 1 numerical values, and default ascending order). To demonstrate this, open the Chrome Dev Tools console, enter `[true, false, false, true].sort()`, and the result is `[false, false, true, true]`.

Comment: Interesting. I will give this a shot and get back. Thank you!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!